# Passing string array parameters to Invoke method

Tags: c#, reflection

I have this class:

```
using System.Linq;
  namespace TestNamespace {
     public class Program {
         public static void Main(string[] args) {
                //does stuff
          }
      }
    }
```

I am loading the above assembly and want to invoke the method with a string array parameter.

This gives me a null exception:

```
private static object[] parameters = new object[1];
string[] pa = { "1", "2" };
parameters[0] = pa;
//Creating target and other code
bool retVal = (bool)target.Invoke(null, parameters);
```

Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Where's the `NullReferenceException`. Are you sure that you're reflecting the `MethodInfo` correctly and that `target` is not `null`? That's my suspicion as to what's really going on here. If there were a `NullReferenceException` being thrown in the method, it would be wrapped in a `TargetInvocationException` and thus I suspect the `NullReferenceException` is because `target` is null.

To be clear, here's how you load and invoke the method:

```
var target = typeof(Program)
                 .GetMethod("Main", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
bool retVal = (bool)target.Invoke(null, new object[] { pa });
```

The `parameters` parameter to `MethodInfo.Invoke` is an `object[]` with the same number, order and types of the parameters for the method being invoked. In your case, you have a single parameter of type `string[]`. Thus, the `object[]` parameter to `MethodInfo.Invoke` should be an array with one element, and that element is an instance of `string[]`. That is what I have accomplished with the syntax above.

Comment: Did you mean `bool retVal = (bool)target.Invoke(null, new object[] { pa });` ? Your syntax gave a `{"Object of type 'System.Object[]' cannot be converted to type 'System.String[]'."}`